# Can I store information in a Static Variable in a SQL Server CLR Assembly without using UNSAFE?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a natural language processing/sentence tagging routine that has been developed as a sqlserver clr assembly written in c#. The routine requires a model file (developed with training data) about 20MB for the computation and I try to load the model file to a static field when the function is called for the first time. However, it seems PERMISSION_SET=EXTERNAL_ACCESS does not allow write to a static field. Of course having an UNSAFE assembly would address the problem but my DBA doesn't like the idea at all. And it makes no sense to me to load the 20MB model file every time the function is called. Is there anyway to store some information in assembly without using UNSAFE.

Comment: Build a separate process to handle the maintenance of the model file. You don't need to load it every time. Just load it once, and update it as needed. Then your CLR function can just reference the table you maintain.

Comment: Tabasco: where you ever able to get this working? Did you try my suggestion of marking the variable as `readonly`?

Comment: I tried the `readonly` keyword but didn't work. We stuck with UNSAFE assembly

Comment: Hi there. Sorry, I didn't see your message until a moment ago. If you want someone to be notified of a message, you need to include their `@` login name in the message. The O.P. of the question of answer being commented on always gets notified of new comments, which is why you got notified about this even though I didn't include your `@` login name. However, if there is only one person (besides the O.P. of the question or answer) commenting, then it will notify that person if the O.P. responds. But as soon as a 2nd person comments it will then require the `@` login name. HTH :-)

Comment: Please see the update I just made to my answer. I suggest a way to get this working such that the Assembly can be marked as `SAFE` :-).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the model file (i.e. the value of the static variable) does not change after being loaded, you should be able to set the static variable as `readonly` which can be set in a constructor in the same class or upon declaration.

Here is the MSDN page for [readonly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

Another option is to modify your code to place that data inside of a Collection, and then mark that Collection as `readonly`. Once marked as `readonly`, the Collection cannot be reassigned, BUT you can still use the `Add` and `Remove` methods to add elements to it and remove elements from it. This will allow you to mark the Assembly as `SAFE`. Please see my answer to another S.O. question for more details:

[Is it safe to change static readonly variables in C# SQLCLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062774/is-it-safe-to-change-static-readonly-variables-in-c-sharp-sqlclr/41063672#41063672)